# Opening of a helix

Tags: geometry

> Consider a helix with its axis along the $z$ axis with its base at the origin and total height $H$. The radius of each turn is $R$ and I need to find the length of the helix.

**My attempt:**

We can easily find the number of turns as $\frac{H}{p}$ and I know that we have to find the length of one turn and multiply it with the total number of turns. My professor told me that we have to open the helix in order to find the length of one turn of the helix and the length of one turn will be the hypotenuse of a triangle with the other two sides being the pitch and $2\pi R$. Using Pythagorean Theorem we can find the length of one turn. However, I am unable to understand how to open the helix and how the two sides of the triangle became the pitch and circumference of one turn.

Comment: The helix is wound around a cylinder. Imagine a line along the length of the cylinder starting at one end of the helix. Hold the end of the helix at the start of the line, and roll the cylinder away from the line.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ce64D_yGDvY (the term spiral is inappropriate)

Comment: thanks dude! I got it now!